# How to actually test a Shopify recurring charge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I am writing a [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) app that apply a recurring charge using Rails. When running: `ShopifyAPI::RecurringApplicationCharge.get(1076285)` I get:

```
{"activated_on"=>"2015-01-17",
 "api_client_id"=>414133,
 "billing_on"=>"2015-01-17",
 "cancelled_on"=>nil,
 "created_at"=>"2015-01-17T11:44:09+07:00",
 "id"=>1076285,
 "name"=>"Business",
 "price"=>"99.90",
 "return_url"=>
  "https://test14sl.myshopify.com/admin/apps/mshopdev//shops/confirm",
 "status"=>"active",
 "test"=>nil,
 "trial_days"=>0,
 "trial_ends_on"=>"2015-01-17",
 "updated_at"=>"2015-01-17T11:46:24+07:00",
 "decorated_return_url"=>
  "https://test14sl.myshopify.com/admin/apps/mshopdev//shops/confirm?charge_id=1076285"}
```

Now seding a get request to: `https://test14sl.myshopify.com/admin/recurring_application_charges.json`

it gives me:

`{"recurring_application_charges":[]}`

How can I make sure that at the end of the 30 days cycle, I see my app payment entry in the user's receipt/invoice?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this info?
I've checked the recurring_application_charges.json in a production store with store owner logged in and I get the same. So I guess [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) has an issue in the API docs on this.
If you check by providing the specific charge ID, I'm positive you'll get the answer. Try to do a `GET` to this: 
`/admin/recurring_application_charges/#{id}.json`

Comment: Yes and I have posted the result of `GET` in my question already. Seems like I have to wait to the end of the 30 cycle to really make sure that I can charge my customers